# html form checkbox not positioning as expect

Tags: html, css

hello i'm creating a login form .but my check box and term text related to it not positioning correctly .i have add `<br>` tag but no effect .i tried `clearfix` it's not work either.here is the [fiddle preview](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxsy864/).

[image]

this is my html code

```
  <div class="mainlog">
     <form>
        <label class="la" for="xname">Name</label><input name="xname" class="in" value="" type="text"><br>
        <label class="la" for="xemail">Email</label><input name="xemail" class="in" value="" type="text"><br>
        <label class="la" for="xpass">password</label><input name="xpass" class="in" value="" type="text"><br>
        <label class="la" for="xpasscon">confirm</label><input name="xpasscon" class="in" value="" type="text"><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="term"/><label class="lb" for="term" >I have read and agree to the Terms of Use and the Privacy Policy</label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>     
  </div>
```

Comment: What *should* it look like? BTW `<center>` is invalid.

Comment: @j08691 checkbox should positioning at new line after confirm field

Comment: @j08691 center invalid ?? what?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. **Do not use it in old or new projects.** Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."

Comment: <center> is invalid in HTML5.

Comment: ohh i never new that.but even i remove center no effect on checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the checkbox and text in a div and float it left. **Avoid the usage of `<center>` it will not be supported in HTML5**

```css
.mainlog {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.in {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.la {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #6B6B6B;
  clear: both;
}
.lb {} .checkbox {
  float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="mainlog">
    <form>
      <label class="la" for="xname">Name</label>
      <input name="xname" class="in" value="" type="text">
      <br>
      <label class="la" for="xemail">Email</label>
      <input name="xemail" class="in" value="" type="text">
      <br>
      <label class="la" for="xpass">password</label>
      <input name="xpass" class="in" value="" type="text">
      <br>
      <label class="la" for="xpasscon">confirm</label>
      <input name="xpasscon" class="in" value="" type="text">
      <br>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="term" />
        <label class="lb" for="term">I have read and agree to the Terms of Use and the Privacy Policy</label>
        <br />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: yes this  works .i warped it inside a field-set ones and got correct output.i'm wondering why is  this behavior occur

Comment: Other elements are set with a float rule while this wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: wrapp checkbox with it's label into div with class "width".
Then in CSS add ".width" with styles: width:100%; clear:both.

```
.width{

    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxsy864/1/)

Answer (score -1):

I did a minor change in your code and it looks good to me. I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Please check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxsy864/2/).

These were the changes I made.

HTML:

```
<div class="lb"> <!-- added class "lb" to <div> and removed it from <label> -->
   <input type="checkbox" name="term"  />
   <label for="term">I have read and agree to the Terms of Use and the Privacy Policy</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lb {
    float:left; /* Floats the element to left */
}
```

I hope this works for you. :)

**P.S.** I have removed all the `<br>` tags inside the `<form>`